# Confused by JavaScript syntax

Tags: javascript

I'm reviewing some code and can't figure out what this means:

`(attrs = {})[key] = val;`

`key` and `val` are both string variables.

Is it a shortcut for an if condition? An object declaration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(attrs = {})[key] = val;
```

is equivalent to

```
attrs = {};
attrs[key] = value;
```

That is, the variable *assignment* in the expression happens first and then the object (the result of the assignment) is modified via a normal property assignment.

I would personally use the latter form here.

Comment: So in other words it is declaring an object and assigning a value to a member of the object at the same time.  In my opinion it's the sort of "clever" programming trick which saves a couple of characters and makes the code way more difficult to maintain for the next guy!

Answer (score 1):

Similar to math, in javascript, anything that happens in `()` will go occur first. The exception is in function definitions which are strictly for declaration.

The expression, as denoted by `()` will execute prior to the rest of the code and return the value inside. This is used in multiple places such as immediately executing function expressions, or in places where a comma is used to build a return value in an expression.

In your case, the `(attrs = {})` expression will return an object, while also assigning that object to the variable attrs. The next code will act on that returned object, accessing a property of the object through `[]` notation at `key` and then assigning that to `value`.